# How to optimize my performances using FlatFileItemReader and Asynchronous Processors

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have a simple csv file with ~400,000 line(one column only)
It takes me alot of time to read the records and process them

the processor validating records against couchbase

the writer - writing into remote topic
Takes me around 30 mins. thats insane.

I read that flatfileItemreader is not thread safe. so my chunk value is 1.

I read the Asynchronous processing could assist. but I cant see any improvements.

Thats my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class NotificationFileProcessUploadedFileJob {


    @Value("${expected.snid.header}")
    public String snidHeader;

    @Value("${num.of.processing.chunks.per.file}")
    public int numOfProcessingChunksPerFile;

    @Autowired
    private InfrastructureConfigurationConfig infrastructureConfigurationConfig;

    private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;


    @Inject
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Inject
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Inject
    ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextPromotionListener;


    @Bean
    public Job processUploadedFileJob() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("processUploadedFileJob").start((processSnidUploadedFileStep())).build();

    }

    @Bean
    public Step processSnidUploadedFileStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processSnidFileStep")
                .<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO>chunk(numOfProcessingChunksPerFile)
                .reader(snidFileReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .processor(asyncItemProcessor())
                .writer(asyncItemWriter())
            //    .throttleLimit(20)
             //   .taskJobExecutor(infrastructureConfigurationConfig.taskJobExecutor())


                        //     .faultTolerant()
                        //   .skipLimit(10) //default is set to 0
                        //     .skip(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Inject
    ItemWriter writer;

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter() {
        AsyncItemWriter asyncItemWriter=new AsyncItemWriter();
        asyncItemWriter.setDelegate(writer);
        return asyncItemWriter;
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ItemStreamReader<PushItemDTO> snidFileReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(snidLineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncItemProcessor() {

        AsyncItemProcessor<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO> asyncItemProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor();

        asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION,
                OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION));
        asyncItemProcessor.setTaskExecutor(infrastructureConfigurationConfig.taskProcessingExecutor());

        return asyncItemProcessor;

    }

    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO> processor(@Value("#{jobParameters[pushMessage]}") String pushMessage,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[jobId]}") String jobId,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[taskId]}") String taskId,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[refId]}") String refId,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[url]}") String url,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[targetType]}") String targetType,
                                                             @Value("#{jobParameters[gameType]}") String gameType) {
        return new PushItemProcessor(pushMessage, jobId, taskId, refId, url, targetType, gameType);
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<PushItemDTO> snidLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(true);
        String[] splittedHeader = snidHeader.split(",");
        lineTokenizer.setNames(splittedHeader);
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<PushItemDTO>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(PushItemDTO.class);

        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new PushItemFieldSetMapper());
        return lineMapper;
    }
}


 @Bean
    @Override
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskProcessingExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor simpleAsyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        simpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(300);
        return simpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
    }
```

How do you think I could improve the processing performances and make them faster?
thank you

ItemWriter code:

```
 @Bean
    public ItemWriter writer() {
        return new KafkaWriter();
    }


public class KafkaWriter implements ItemWriter<PushItemDTO> {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaWriter.class);

    @Autowired
    KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends PushItemDTO> items) throws Exception {

        for (PushItemDTO item : items) {
            try {
                logger.debug("Writing to kafka=" + item);
                sendMessageToKafka(item);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error writing item=" + item.toString(), e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code improvement suggestions belong on [Code Review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: chunk size has nothing to do with multi threading. A chunk size of 1 means 1 is read, processed and written. Creating a transaction for each item. Which means ~400000 transactions. Increase the chunk size and you will get more performance. Also you should limit the hand offs ideally the processor and writer should share a thread, currently the processor uses a thread and the writer, which means you pass data between threads which is (relatively) slow.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. Could you answer this question and improve my code when you meant: "Also you should limit the hand offs ideally the processor and writer should share a thread"   .. I didnt understand how it's possible to let them share the same Thread. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing your commit count is where I'd begin.  Keep in mind what the commit count means.  Since you have it set at 1, you are doing the following **for each item**:

1. Start a transaction
2. Read an item
3. Process the item
4. Write the item
5. Update the job repository
6. Commit the transaction

Your configuration doesn't show what the delegate `ItemWriter` is so I can't tell, but at a minimum you are executing multiple SQL statements **per item** to update the job repository.

You are correct in that the `FlatFileItemReader` is not thread safe.  However, you aren't using multiple threads to read, only process so there is no reason to set the commit count to 1 from what I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edited the question with the writer.Have I implemented the asynchronous right (using the asynchronous processors api) ?

Comment: What you have is correct.  However, the `AsyncItemProcessor`/`AsyncItemWriter` will only improve performance in certain situations.  In this case, since you're reading one file, the only way that using them will improve performance is if the bottle neck is the processor or writer.

Comment: could you refer me to an example how I should use the reader in order to split big file into small ones and process each one on diff Thread?