# Spring, FlatFileItemWriter write large file

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to write a large file using FlatFileItemWriter.
When I call the write method, a OutOfMemory occurs.
Is there a way to write large files ?
My writer is defined like this :

```
FlatFileItemWriter<FieldSet> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        File mostRecent = <myFile>
        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(<myTmpFile>);

        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(resource.getFile());
        writer.setResource(resource);
        DelimitedLineAggregator<FieldSet> delimitedLine = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        delimitedLine.setDelimiter(SEPARATOR);
        writer.setLineAggregator(delimitedLine);

        writer.setHeaderCallback(new FlatFileHeaderCallback() {
            public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException
            {
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                for (Column column : Column.values())
                {
                    buffer.append(column.getName());
                    buffer.append(SEPARATOR);
                }
                writer.write(CHAR_FOR_EXCEL + buffer.toString());
            }
        });
        writer.open(new ExecutionContext());

        writer.write(items);
```

Comment: Probably you can use Partitioning/Splitting with Async processing(i.e. asynchronous processors and writer)  for improving performance and memory issue.  Existing thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606634/how-to-optimize-my-performances-using-flatfileitemreader-and-asynchronous-proces

Comment: You should be using Spring Batch for this and not work around that. It is supposed to work with chunks of data. Looking at what you do is that you have some large amount of stuff in memory and write everything at once, instead of using Spring Batch and write chunks of data to the file.